# Surely questions about class struggle are "on topic"?

Tags: discussion

Is this off-topic?

[Is there anything analogous to the withdrawal of labour in a mass strike, on the internet?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/59633/is-there-anything-analogous-to-the-withdrawal-of-labour-in-a-mass-strike-on-the)

Comment: come on guys, work with each other a bit... three close votes no comment?

Comment: This is an example of one of your questions where I actually agree with you that it is on topic and should be reopened. I would urge you to consider the advice Frank gave in his answer; find a prominent Marxist who has talked about information theory and use them to make the question more specific. Although I completely disagree with his assessment of user4894's answer, it is completely off the mark and has nothing to do with the Marxist conception of labor, but you seemed to know as much in your comment responding to it. So ignore that but do the former.

Comment: @Not_Here hmm ok re your first sentence. anyway, i added in some references, so hope that the question is reopened. i believe it is a very *good* question and exactly one that marxists in information science should be asking, even if they are not yet

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I voted in the review queue to leave this open. This was primarily because of comments from @user4894 that I think could be converted into an interesting and unexpected (to me) answer to the question.

Perhaps what might help is a reference to one of the Marxists who "talk about the internet". This would focus the question and make it about that Marxist's views as much as about the topic of using the internet for class struggle in general.

Comment: ok edited now. honestly, and i don't mean to sound hostile, but, i feel that too many users on this site know their stuff but have little insight into it

Comment: @confused We are all learning here. Some of us know more than others in some areas. Just having the opportunity to bounce questions and answers off real people who may or may not be making mistakes makes this site valuable (and entertaining in its own way for me).

Comment: that's a nice, positive, attitude, thanks :)